# SQL Timeout Execution Error [ I am Getting TimeOut execution error in high volume request]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

```
 ![Code Snape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtVCG.png)
```

Everyone
I am Getting SQL Timeout Execution Error while executing my code on load balancer with frequency 2 request in a second. What should i do to resolve my problem.

```
  public IQueryable<Book> GetBookContent(Guid Bookid, string AuthorID, bool includeBookContents = false)
    {

        try
        {
            if (includeBookContents )
            {
                return dbContext.Books.Include("BooksProperties").Include("ProcessedBook").Where(a =>
                            (a.GUID.Equals(Bookid) || a.ParentBook.GUID.Equals(Bookid))
                                  && a.AuthorID.Equals(AuthorID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            }


            else
                return _dbContext.Books.Include("BooksProperties").Include("ProcessedBook").Where(a =>
                    a.GUID.Equals(Bookid) && a.AuthorID.Equals(AuthorID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: better indexes on your tables?

Comment: @BugFinder: I have index on my table with all column except GUID . So do I need to adda  Non-Clustered Index on GUID column as well?

Comment: if you made 1 index with all columns, it wont be using it for this.. ask SQL what indexes would be suitable - as this is likely a small part of your code.

Comment: I have Book Table where I have Non-Clustered Index

1.BookID -> Clustered Index

2.ParentBookID -> Non-Clustered Index

3.GUID

4.AuthorID -> Non-Clustered Index

5.ProcessedBookID ->  Non-Clustered Indexx

Comment: ONLY GUID has no Indexing and i have GUID in Where Condition

Comment: Your condition is guid and author... you should index on the pair.. as I said ask SQL it will tell you what indexes would improve your app

Comment: @bugfinder : can I Break my query in two parts? any way ?

Comment: maybe but that make it way more inefficient.. btw "includeChildContents"? surely the bool is "includeBookContents"?

Comment: Yes includeChildContents is includeBookContents

Comment: can we make two database call to execute  IF condition which has OR based Query??

Comment: What kind of timeout do you get? Seeing your code this can hardly be a command timeout. It's more likely that you execute too many requests per time unit. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: @Gert: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: And I am executing 3 request in 1 second

Comment: Well, you should create an index on Guid anyway, with or without included columns. Let the database engine tuning advisor give you the best option.

Comment: Ok . will give a try by creating Non-ClusterIndex on GUID.

Comment: As i said, you should ask sql, it will be very specific and even tell you how much faster it would make the average query

Answer (score -1):

A solution is to increase the timeout threshold.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

Comment: I have Increased my threshold to 80 .  lthis.Database.CommandTimeout = 80;

Comment: But it didnt solve my problem if  i am doing a request of 120 in 1 min then 80 request get pass but 20-25 got fail.  :(

Comment: find out why your query is taking so long, write a stored procedure in sql and run it in ssms, there you can see the query's execution plan and find out which part is taking so long.
Look here for understanding more about query performance http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html